# How to warn or error when using "npm install"

Tags: pnpm

pnpm uses `pnpm-lock.yaml` as its lock file. I was hoping it might be able to write `package-lock.json` instead for interoperability with npm, but this [doesn't seem to be possible](https://pnpm.io/limitations).

Because of that, when collaborators accidentally run `npm install` instead of `pnpm install`, I'd like to print a warning or better yet, exit with an error, informing them to use `pnpm` instead. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: Related questions: [Preventing npm commands in favor of pnpm](/q/71459020) and [Force yarn install instead of npm install for Node module?](/q/41076172)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with packages such as [only-allow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-allow), [only-allow-engines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-allow-engines), or [only-pnpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-pnpm). These generally work either via a preinstall script or by (ab)using the `"engines"` property in package.json.

The node.js project is working on a better solution: [corepack](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/corepack.html). Corepack will allow projects to specify their desired package manager via the `"packageManager"` property of package.json. However, as of 2022, corepack is still experimental and requires an explicit opt-in step (`corepack enable`). Unless you can rely on all collaborators having it enabled, it's not yet a viable solution.